# Javascript - Get changed value of input onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an empty input in a td and I want to take the value the user is giving in on button click. Here is the code

```js
function change(){
  //alert changed value of x
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>

<body>
 <table>
  
  <tr>
   <td>Length:</td></tr><tr><td> <input type=number name="x" id="x"></td>
  </tr>
    </table>
 <button id="button" onclick="change()"></button><br>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your function `change()` inside the ready function and get value using the id of input `x` :

```
$('#x').val()
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(function(){
     function change(){
          alert( $('#x').val() );
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>Length:</td></tr><tr><td> <input type=number name="x" id="x"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button" onclick="change()">Get value</button><br>
```

Comment: alert returns "undefined"..

Comment: no sorry my bad i forgot '#'! Thanks a lot : )))

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){

    var inputVal = document.querySelectorAll('#x')[0].value;
    alert(inputVal);
  });
});
```

the $(document).ready() function let's jQuery know to begin executing the anonymous function when the DOM loads, and $("#button").click() tells jQuery to begin executing the anonymous function when the button gets clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can Donnerstag this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var data = {
            number: '0', //The initial value if no input or change
            set: function(val) {
                this.number = val;
            }
        };
        function message() {
            // Do smth else
            console.log(data.number);
        }
    </script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Length:</td></tr><tr><td> <input type=number name="x" onChange="data.set(this.value)"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="button" onclick="message()">Klick here</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope I could help you ;)

Comment: Sorry for the "Donnerstag", an autocorrection error I should be the word do

Comment: Thanks Noah! Additional info is always welcome

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to use any other frameworks and you want to reuse this handler without having to customize the selector, you could just use this.

```
 function change(event) {
    console.log(event.srcElement.value);//get the value of the element that triggered the event   
 }
```

You need to pass the "event" as the argument though.

```
<input type="text" onclick="change(event)" />
```